# Auto showing keyboard in swift

Tags: swift, uikeyboard

I need to show the keyboard automatically when I will go to a particular View controller. Let take an example I have two view controller named "A" and "B". I have a text field present in the "B" view controller. When I am navigating from "A" to "B", I need to show the keyboard automatically. How to do it?

Comment: Make the textfield in B firstresponder in B's viewDidAppear Method. Resign firstResponder on ViewWillDisappear or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in B view controller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type it in your `B` ViewController

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.yourTextFieldName.delegate = self
        self.showKeyBoard()
    }

    func showKeyBoard(){
        self.yourTextFieldName.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```